# MySQL Min(), MAX() using the IDs from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two very simple MySQL tables: **Table1** with a list of unique item_ids and the second one **Table2** with records using the the item ids form the first table.  **Table2** contains also the date the record was made. To recap here is how the tables look like:

**Table1**
columns: **item_id** <---these are unique IDs

**Table2**
columns: **item_id, item_title, time_stamp**

What I need is a MySQL query that will give me a list with the date of the first and last record have been made for each item_id in **Table2**.  It's imperative that **Table2** will look just for the item_id in Table1 because **Table2** contains item_ids that are not contained in **Table1**. So in other words I'm using **Table1** just for sorting based on item_id.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  t2.item_id, MIN(t2.time_stamp), MAX(t2.time_stamp)
FROM    table2 t2
JOIN    table1 t1
ON      t1.item_id = t2.item_id
GROUP BY
        t1.item_id
ORDER BY
        t1.ordering_column
```

In `MySQL`, you can use ungrouped and unaggregated expressions in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Probably want to edit and add the group key to the select list to give context to the dates

Comment: aren't MAX() and MIN() aggregated expressions?

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_id, maxts.ts, mints.ts
from (select item_id, max(time_stamp) as ts from Table2 group by item_id) maxts
join (select item_id, min(time_stamp) from Table2 group by item_id) mints on maxts.item_id=mints.item_id
join Table1.item_id t1 on t1.item_id=mints.item_id;
```